Qt Designer: Display a List of Enum Options in Custom Widget Properties Editor Using Python
I'm working on creating a custom widget for Qt Designer in Python using PyQt or PySide. I want to expose an enum property in the Qt Designer property editor, so that users can select from a list of predefined options rather than typing in arbitrary values.
In C++, it is possible to expose an enum to Qt Designer using Q_ENUMS and Q_PROPERTY, as described in this Stack Overflow question.
I want to achieve the same result in Python. Specifically, I want to:

Define an enum in Python that can be used as a property in my custom widget.
Ensure that this enum is displayed as a dropdown list in the Qt Designer property editor.

Here's an outline of what I have so far:

from qtpy.QtCore import Qt, QEasingCurve, QPropertyAnimation, QSize, Property, QPoint, QEnum
from qtpy.QtWidgets import QCheckBox, QApplication, QLabel
from enum import Enum

class EasingCurveEnum(Enum):
    Option1 = 0
    Option2 = 1
    Option3 = 2

class QCustomCheckBox(QCheckBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self._easing_curve = EasingCurveEnum.Option1
        # ...

    @Property(EasingCurveEnum, designable=True)
    def animationEasingCurve(self):
        return self._easing_curve
    
    @animationEasingCurve.setter
    def animationEasingCurve(self, curve):
        self._easing_curve = curve


How can I make the EasingCurveEnum property appear as a list of options in the Qt Designer property editor?
I've successfully registered my custom widget in Qt Designer, but the enum list property is not appearing.
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks in advance!
UPDATE:
Tried this, it didn't work:
@QEnum
class EasingCurveEnum(Enum):
....

I also tried this, did not work either:

class EasingCurveEnum(Enum):
    Option1 = 0
    Option2 = 1
    Option3 = 2

class QCustomCheckBox(QCheckBox):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
         #tried.....
        QEnum(EasingCurveEnum)

        self._easing_curve = EasingCurveEnum.Option1
        # ...

    @Property(EasingCurveEnum, designable=True)
    def animationEasingCurve(self):
        return self._easing_curve
    
    @animationEasingCurve.setter
    def animationEasingCurve(self, curve):
        self._easing_curve = curve




I don't know how they're really named (even assuming they're supported) on qtpy, but PyQt provides the Q_ENUM (and the deprecated Q_ENUMS) in form of decorators, that can then be used in classes similarly to the signal and property ones.

As said, I don't know how qtpy deals with this specific case (you should check their docs), but in any case using QEnum() for the instance makes no sense, since it must be a class member. As already written, the enum must be defined and eventually decorated at the class level exactly like signals and properties. Check the related PySide and PyQt docs, and consider implementing them based on the currently loaded python binding in case qtpy doesn't work.

You'll need to make some adjustments to your code :

Instead of using Python's Enum class, use QtCore.QEnum to define your enum.

2.Define the enum inside your custom widget class.
3.Use the Q_ENUMS macro (implemented as a class decorator in PyQt/PySide) to register the enum with Qt's meta-object system.
Here's an updated version of your code that should work:
from qtpy.QtCore import Qt, QObject, Property, QEnum
from qtpy.QtWidgets import QCheckBox
class QCustomCheckBox(QCheckBox):
class EasingCurveEnum(QObject):
Option1 = 0
Option2 = 1
Option3 = 2
# Register the enum with Qt's meta-object system
EasingCurveEnum = QEnum(EasingCurveEnum)

def __init__(self, parent=None):
    super().__init__(parent)
    self._easing_curve = self.EasingCurveEnum.Option1

@Property(EasingCurveEnum, designable=True)
def animationEasingCurve(self):
    return self._easing_curve

@animationEasingCurve.setter
def animationEasingCurve(self, curve):
    self._easing_curve = curve

These changes should make the animationEasingCurve property appear as a dropdown list in the Qt Designer property editor.

You say that QEnum should be used instead of Python Enum, yet you define the enum as a QObject, which makes absolutely no sense at all. Then you suggest to use the Q_ENUMS (even though it's been deprecated since almost 10 years) but there's no trace of that in your code. Note that if you've used a generative AI to write this, then be aware that such content is banned on StackOverflow and may cause suspension. If you did not, then you should really write your answers and, most importantly, their code much more thoughtfully.

You're correct that my previous suggestion was flawed. Using QObject for the enum definition and mentioning Q_ENUMS without actually using it was a mistake. we can use QtCore.QEnum to define an enum that Qt's property system can recognize.

Then create a proper [mre], test it, ensure that it works as expected (including the Qt Designer plugin compliance or, at least, the QMetaObject availability), then eventually [edit] your post with the corrected code. Also, always ensure that you format code properly by checking the post preview before submitting.
